# Issues regarding alarm notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Hiii

I am trying to develop an alarm notification in android using broadcast receiver and alarm manager.I have tried to develop code where I am able to set alarm,but the problem is after setting alarm  i should get some reminder notification.But its not working...Please suggest something..

here is the code

Alarm.java

```
public class Alarm extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    TimePicker myTimePicker;
     Button buttonstartSetDialog;
     TextView textAlarmPrompt;


     TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

     final static int RQS_1 = 1;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
        textAlarmPrompt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
         buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
         buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                   textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                    openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }
        });

    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

          timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                  Alarm.this, 
            onTimeSetListener, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            is24r);
          timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

          timePickerDialog.show();

         }

            OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
            = new OnTimeSetListener(){

          @Override
          public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

           Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
           Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

           calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
           calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
           calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

           if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
            //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
           }

           setAlarm(calSet);
          }};

         private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

          textAlarmPrompt.setText(
            "\n\n***\n"
            + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "***\n");

          Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

         }

        }
```

AlarmReciever.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

ManifestFile.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notificationalarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationalarm.Alarm"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please Help...

Comment: Check this http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/ and http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/android-sdk-add-a-repeating-alarmmanager-to-the-autostart-displaying-messages-in-the-notification-bar/

Answer (score 0):

As i found in your above code that there is no notification code is used to create notification in broadcast receiver.I suggest u use this use this...http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/12/android-alarm-manager-example-how-to.html for reference and see this code for create notification in receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String SOMEACTION = "com.manish.alarm.ACTION";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?");
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (SOMEACTION.equals(action)) {
        //do what you want here
        generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
      System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2");
      int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
      long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
      String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
      String subTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, OutPut.class);
      notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);
      PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
      notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
      //To play the default sound with your notification:
      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
      notificationManager.notify(0, notification);



}
```

}

Comment: Sorry my friend. I didn't downvote your answer. I just added the comment. It is someone else in the community.